# why carrier wave changing the path of existng uploaded Files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrier wave for uploading files. For testing purposes, I have uploaded three files and they were uploaded properly. Below was my directory path.

```
        def store_dir
          "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
         end
```

Later on I changed the directory path to

```
         def store_dir
             "D:/source/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
          end
```

But when I checked the path of the previously uploaded files, with below command:

```
           s.avatar.url
```

it is showing me new path as `D:/source/student/avatar/8/7zip.msi`. How will I get the old path of this object?

Comment: Mb better just move folders from `public/uploads` of your project to `D:/source/` folder?

Comment: "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}" This was the old path of the object  and when i override the store_dir method to " "D:/source/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}" it is swoing me different path dont know why... i wat to know that how i will be able to get the old path .